# How to redirect user to play store?

Tags: android-studio

I am putting link(URL) of my an other app inside my popular app so when user clicks it will redirect to another app in play store I am doing it by using this code but it is violating the made for ads policy how can I do it without violating the policy?

````
try { 
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
    String shareMessage= "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
    shareMessage = shareMessage + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +"\n\n";
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);  
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "choose one"));
} catch(Exception e) { 
    //e.toString();
}   ```
````

Answer (score 0):

This will violate Google Ad privacy policy. If you have to do this you should put a small image written `Ad` in it or just add text `(Ad)` in the link like

**Other App (Ad)**

This will tell user you are promoting some app your or someone else's. And it will not violate any privacy policy.

Comment: Are you sure it won't violate privacy policy just by writing "ad" with it?

Comment: Yes, Because you are promoting some other application and the terms says you have to explicitly mention it's an Ad. Better option is to put a small image with yellow background with having text in white color.